# MERN Redux TypeError: conversations.map is not a function redux

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redux, react-redux

I have a component that needs to access state in a reducer.
When I call the useSelector to get the state, at first its an empty object, then about 3 seconds later, BAM data comes in.

I want to run a .find or .map on this data in the component to see if some values match.

The page loads for about 3 seconds, then bam, TypeError: conversations.map is not a function

Here is my component below

```
import React, { useState, useContext} from 'react';
import { TabContent, TabPane } from 'reactstrap';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import ChatContentHeader from './ChatContentHeader';
import MessageTextArea from './MessageTextArea';
import ChatContentBody from './ChatContentBody';
import { ChatContext } from '../../../context/Context';

const ChatContent = () => {
  
  const { threads, activeThreadId, selContact, activeConversationId, setSelContact } = useContext(ChatContext);
  const thread = threads.find(({ id }) => id === activeThreadId); 
  const [isOpenThreadInfo, setIsOpenThreadInfo] = useState(false);
  const conversationCreate = useSelector((state) => state.conversationCreate)
  const conversations = useSelector((state) => state.conversations)


  
  const conversation = conversations.map((c) => console.log(c)) <---- this is getting error .map is not a function... same thing if try .find instead.
// this is crashing the app the second the data hits the component.
//If I comment this out, and console.log(conversations) I see the data just fine

  console.log(conversations)
 
  return (
   
    <TabContent className="card-chat-content fs--1 position-relative">
      <TabPane className="card-chat-pane active">
        <ChatContentHeader thread={thread} setIsOpenThreadInfo={setIsOpenThreadInfo} />
        <ChatContentBody thread={thread} isOpenThreadInfo={isOpenThreadInfo} />
      </TabPane>

      <MessageTextArea thread={thread} selContact={selContact} />
    </TabContent>
    
  );
};

export default ChatContent;
```

Here is the reducer

```
const LIST_CONVERSATIONS = 'list_conversations';


export default function (state = [ ], action) {
    switch (action.type) {

        case LIST_CONVERSATIONS:
            return action.payload  
            default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Here is the action creator

```
export const listConversations = () => {
        return async function(dispatch) {
                await 
                axios({
                 url:"http://localhost:5000/conversations",
                 method:"GET", 
                 withCredentials: true
                 }).then( res => dispatch({type: LIST_CONVERSATIONS, payload: res}))
                 }
         }
```

Here is my backend function being called by action creator

```
const listConversations = async (req, res) => {
     const { subActServiceSid, subActAuthToken, convoServiceSid} = req.user
     const subClient = require('twilio')(subActServiceSid, subActAuthToken)
     const allConversationSids = []
     const allParticipantSids = []
     const allMessages = []
     await subClient.conversations.services(convoServiceSid)
     .conversations
     .list()
     .then(conversations => conversations.forEach(c => allConversationSids.push(c.sid))); 
     await Promise.all(allConversationSids.map( async (convo) => {
        await subClient.conversations.services(convoServiceSid)
        .conversations(convo)
        .participants
        .list({limit: 20})
        .then(participants => participants.forEach(p => allParticipantSids.push({"conversationSid": p.conversationSid, "participantSid": p.sid, "messagesId": p.conversationSid}) ));
     }))
     res.json(allParticipantSids)
    
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works before the API results come back, which means that your initial state   `[]` is fine, and the state which is being set by your action is something which is not an array.  If it's not an array then it won't have functions `.map` and `.find`.

Your problem is right here:

```
then( res => dispatch({type: LIST_CONVERSATIONS, payload: res}))
```

You are dispatching the entire axios response object in your action payload.  That response object is not an array.  The array that you want should be on the`.data` property of the response.

```
then( res => dispatch({type: LIST_CONVERSATIONS, payload: res.data}))
```

Comment: Linda YOU ARE ABSOLUTELY CORRECT OMG THANK YOU